# Should “The man has always needed religion and as profoundly as he has always needed food” use a simple tense instead?

Tags: grammaticality, perfect-aspect, past-vs-present-perfect

Should this sentence's verbs indicate that the actions occurred in the past *indirectly* by using the compound **present** prefect construction:

> The man **has** always **needed** religion and as profoundly as he **has** always **needed** food.

Or should it indicate that the actions occurred in the past *directly* by using the simple **past** tense:

> The man always **needed** religion and as profoundly as he always **needed** food.

Comment: Are you specifically asking whether the present perfect is correct as opposed to the simple past?

Comment: I think you are referring to human beings, all of us, right? Not to a particular man?

Comment: Remove the **and**. Both are correct. As with most SP and PP questions, it all depends on what **you want to say**. The continues continues to be true the second implies the man is dead or no longer within your bailiwick.

Comment: @Lambie It would be correct without the "and", but it's also correct with it. The writer is trying to say, first, man has always needed religion, and then second, he has always needed it just as profoundly as he has needed food. Without the "and" you lose the idea of the two steps.

Comment: You probably mean "**Man** has always needed..." (that is, *man* as a general concept, or men in general), not "*The man has always needed...", because *the man* refers to a specific man.

Comment: With the **and** it is poorly parenthetical. In any event, the sentence is not a compound sentence as written. It's fine for literature but I would not try and get an ELL to use it. There is simply no need for the and. A good editor would remove it. A compound sentence has to have parallel structure, and these do not.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. The first indicates a continuous need. The second could strictly literally be understood to mean that this is a need that existed in the past but no longer exists, but in context, unless the author specifically says that he thinks the situation has changed, we would probably understand him to mean that this phenomenon continues.